# python append two matrix side by side

Tags: python, numpy

I am having some problem with python.

```
    A= [ [1,2,3]
         [4,5,6]
       ]

   B = [ [10,11]
         [12,13]
       ]
```

I want to have:

```
   C = [A B]
     = [ [1,2,3,  10, 11]
         [4,5,6,  12, 13]
       ]
```

How do I do that in python?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are describing the basic usage of [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html).

```
np.hstack((A, B))
```

There is also an equivalent index trick:

```
np.c_[A, B]
```

Answer (score 13):

Also, using [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) with `axis=1` will be **4x** faster than using `numpy.hstack`.

```
In [207]: np.concatenate((A, B), axis=1)
Out[207]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3, 10, 11],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 12, 13]])
```

---

And if you care about performance, [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) is the real war horse.

```
In [215]: %timeit np.concatenate((A, B), 1)
The slowest run took 12.10 times longer than the fastest.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.1 µs per loop

In [214]: %timeit np.hstack((A,B))
The slowest run took 6.85 times longer than the fastest.
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.5 µs per loop

In [216]: %timeit np.c_[A, B]
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.7 µs per loop
```

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that `np.hstack` actually uses `np.concatenate`, so it can *never* be faster.  We should prefer to use the higher-level API, unless maximum performance is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, basically adding each list in the zipped (A, B) object:

```
>>> [x + y for x, y in zip(A, B)]
[[1, 2, 3, 10, 11], [4, 5, 6, 12, 13]]
```

Answer (score 1):

can't tell if you're asking about numpy arrays (per your tag) or lists of lists (matrix per your title)... but:

to concatenate lists you just add them together:

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
B = [[10,11],[12,13]]
C = [A[0]+B[0],A[1]+B[1]]

print C

>>>
[[1, 2, 3, 10, 11], [4, 5, 6, 12, 13]]
```

if you have arrays to begin with you can use the append method:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
B = np.array([[10,11],[12,13]])
C = np.array([np.append(A[0],B[0]),np.append(A[1],B[1])])

print C

>>>
[[ 1  2  3 10 11]
 [ 4  5  6 12 13]]
```