# How to concatenate two different into one array

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays of arrays:

```
[array[(1, 2, 3)],
array[(4, 5, 6, 7)],
array[(8, 9, 9.5)]]

[array[(10, 11, 12)],
array[(13, 14, 15)],
array[(16, 17, 18, 19)]]
```

What I need to have is:

```
[[array([1, 2, 3]),
  array([10, 11, 12])],
 [array([4, 5, 6, 7]),
  array([13, 14, 15])],
 [array([7, 8, 9.5]),
  array([16, 17, 18, 19])]]
```

I can do by looping into the two arrays but it not really productif, any idea guys on how I could do that without looping? many thanks for any advice!

Comment: Do all inner arrays have the same shape?

Comment: in the example yes, but in my source code no unfortunately...

Comment: Here is the exact solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334040/python-append-two-matrix-side-by-side

Comment: It is not possible to do this **without** looping, but you can do it without **explicit** looping: `list(map(list, zip(a, b)))`, but it will not be buying you any significant speed-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `zip` built-in function:

```
[list(x) for x in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Similarly:

```
list(map(list, zip(list1, list2)))
```